# java.io.NotSerializableException: For RowSet

Tags: java, jdbc, rowset

I am trying to print out the contents of row set to a file but I am getting java.io.NotSerializableException:

Here is my program..

```
package k564;

import java.io.*;
import javax.sql.RowSet;
import com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl;

public class Lab15a {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    RowSet rs= new JdbcRowSetImpl();
    rs.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbc");
    rs.setUsername("root");
    rs.setPassword("123");
    rs.setCommand("select cid,cname,cemail,cphone,camount from customer");
    rs.execute();

    while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getInt("cid")+"\t"+rs.getString("cname")+"\t"+rs.getString("cemail")+"\t"+rs.getInt("cphone")+rs.getInt("camount"));          
    }

    rs.beforeFirst();
    System.out.println("Serialixzing Rowset");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("d:\\rowset.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(rs);
    System.out.println("serialized");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

}

Error that I am getting.

Error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at k564.Lab15a.main(Lab15a.java:33)
```

I am not able to figure out what is wrong here?

Comment: You print the stack trace, what does it say?

Comment: Even if your object was serializable, it would not be human readable if this is what you want.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I have printed the error that I am getting.

Comment: @StephaneM I want to store it in a file.

Answer (score 1):

Java's `ObjectOuputStream` can only serialize objects which implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface. `JdbcRowSet` class does not implement this interface.

To print out the contents, try to use `getRow()`, `toString()` or something similar to achieve your goal.

Comment: But `JdbcRowSetImpl` extrends `BaseRowSet` which implements `Serializable`

Comment: @Csuki I am trying to store it in a file. Oh! I did not mention that.

Comment: @zencv, Anyidea of where I am making a mistake.

Comment: @user2900314 probably you have to use a diff. implementation as I had mentioned in my answer. I haven't tested the code though

Answer (score 0):

According to [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/rowset.html),

> Disconnected RowSet objects have all the capabilities of connected
>   RowSet objects plus they have the additional capabilities available
>   only to disconnected RowSet objects. For example, not having to
>   maintain a connection to a data source makes disconnected RowSet
>   objects far more lightweight than a JdbcRowSet object or a ResultSet
>   object. Disconnected RowSet objects are also serializable, and the
>   combination of being both serializable and lightweight makes them
>   ideal for sending data over a network.

I recommend using a `CachedRowSet` which according to doc may be more suitable for serializing

You can also think of creating a Customer class which implements `Serializable` with fields like `cid,cname,cemail,cphone,camount` to represent the values read from the database. Then map the values from Resultset to the values of the column using setters for each field and then you can serialize the `Customer` class to the output file.

Note: If you want to serialize an Object, the class must implement Serializable and you are strongly recommended to also add a serialVersionUID to represent the version number

Comment: Sorry, These are going way above my head. I shall definitely try implementing the same using a CachedRowSet. RowSet objects are connectionless objects right and moreover since its implementing serializable imterface why am i getting this error?